# How do I retrieve parent object with child object while having OneToMany bidriectional relationship in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I am new to Spring boot. please help me with the below issue:

I am getting only child object data while retrieving using join query..

Below is my child entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tenant_user_configuration")
public class TenantUserConfiguration {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "config_key")
private String configKey;

@Column(name = "config_value")
private String configValue;

private String system;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="tenant_user_id",referencedColumnName = "tenant_user_id")
@JsonBackReference
private TenantUser tenantUser;
```

This is my parent entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tenant_user")
public class TenantUser {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "tenant_user_id")
private int tenantUserId;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id",referencedColumnName = "tenant_id")
private Tenant tenant;

@Column(name = "user_name")
private String userName;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "enabled")
private boolean enabled;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenantUser",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<TenantUserConfiguration> tenantUserConfiguration = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Could you please share the SQL query you are looking for or the method of your parent repository component.

Comment: Thanks for help! this is the query:                                
 @Query("from TenantUserConfiguration t join t.tenantUser where t.tenantUser.enabled='true'")

Comment: It sounds that your jpql query is correct, except that fetch type of tenantUser in TenantUserConfiguration is LAZY, change it to EAGER and give it a try.

Comment: It did not work actually and  the default fetch type for ManyToOne is EAGER only. Though thanks for helping

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: No I did not get any exception the application results the same way

Comment: What do you mean by "I am getting only child object data", what happens when you call getTenantUser?

Comment: @VitalyChura I am only getting the data from child entity(tenantuserConfig) and not parent entity(tenantUser)

Comment: What do you mean by that? Is tenantUser field null or what?

Comment: I am executing this query @Query("from TenantUserConfiguration t join t.tenantUser where t.tenantUser.enabled='true'").So I wnat data from both the table as I have done foreign key mapping

Comment: If you want to get TenantUsers why don't you do : `@Query("from TenantUser t  where t.enabled='true'")`